# Debugging grails 3.3.11 project in IntelliJ Idea Community

Tags: intellij-idea, grails

I am trying to debug my grails 3.3.11 source code using a community version of IntelliJ Idea. I don't know why but, even if a choose a break point, I run the command
grails run-app -debug
as I have seen in a variety of sites, the application never stops in the breakpoint. It executes all the program.

I have two questions.
1 - Is it possible to debug a grails 3.3.11 project using the community version of IntelliJ Idea?
2 - If so, how can I do that.

Thanks,

Alfredo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I have two questions. 1 - Is it possible to debug a grails 3.3.11 project using the community version of IntelliJ Idea?
```

Yes.  The debugger in the community version of Intellij works well with Grails.

```
2 - If so, how can I do that.
```

There are a number of ways.  You can create a run-configuration in IntelliJ to launch the application in debug mode.  You can launch the application using `./gradlew bootRun --debug-jvm` and then attach a remote debugger from the IDE (I do that all the time).  The video at https://grails.org/blog/2017-01-20-4.html demonstrates using the debugger (that portion works the same in Community Edition vs Ultimate Edition).

Comment: Another relevant video is available at https://grails.org/blog/2018-08-22-1.html.

Comment: Perfect! Debugger now working as expected. Thanks a lot
@Jeff Scott Brown